# Facebook Open Graph custom action Profile property URL format

Tags: rest, facebook-opengraph

I have defined a custom Action in Open Graph which takes as its Object the built-in type Profile. Basically it is a player v player game, and you can "Beat" another player when you win.

In the Graph API explorer, I am able to submit calls fine if I set my profile parameter using the person's username, e.g.

```
    profile = http://facebook.com/fredbloggs
```

But I can't figure out any format that works if all I have is the profile id. None of the following work:

```
    profile = http://facebook.com/profile.php?id=1232123123
    profile = http://facebook.com/1232123123
    profile = https//graph.facebook.com/1232123123
    profile = 1232123123
```

They all give "An unexpected error has occurred. Please retry your request later"

What is the correct format for profile URLs using IDs?

Comment: To clarify, I'm trying to do a call like:

Comment: `https://graph.facebook.com/me/shuurofb:beat?profile=http://facebook.com/123131232&access_token=... ` But it doesn't work unless I use the username instead of user id

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer may be in the [documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/objects/builtin/#external_profile).

Note that the section heading read "Profile (External)".  The URL that worked for you leads to the externally visible profile for the user.  I found that I could put the user id, as well as an externally visible profile link like yours, (http://facebook.com/fredbloggs), in the sample object in the Open Graph dashboard for my application without causing a parser error.  The action however, did not do anything with the user id value.  When I changed the sample value to a non-existent user id, I received a parsing error.

Answer (score 0):

This one is correct:
     profile = https//graph.facebook.com/1232123123

Though you are missing a colon:
     profile = https://graph.facebook.com/1232123123

That just gives user info. Depending on what you want you may need to add a /feed or whatever you want. See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/

Comment: No that doesn't work. I'm not trying to use the Graph API to retrieve a profile, I'm trying to use the new Open Graph API, and pass in a profile URL as the Object for an Action.

Answer (score 0):

No-one seemed to have an answer for this. The format http://facebook.com/235612356 would have seemed the most likely, but redirects and so perhaps that is the issue.

Also, appears that the built-in Profile type had other issues as it appeared in the OAuth Dialog as a "musician", so our game claimed to allow you to "beat musicians". I guess it was added for Spotify integration, and isn't really quite working yet.

Anyway, I eventually went with another solution which was to make my own Object type called "opponent" and dynamically create Open Graph pages at URLs like http://example-site.com/player/1232189. More work, but works correctly and means clicking on an "opponent" links to a page on our site rather than a user Facebook page, which is more useful anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is a bug. I have create a bug in their [bug tracking system](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/423035704395311).